# Boolean operation with byte

Tags: c, boolean

There is a line of code  that reads

```
while(!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG))
```

`IFG2` is an 8 bit register, whose 2nd LSB is `UCA0TXIFG`. Under this context, I thought the argument of while() had to be boolean. How would `IFG2&UCA0TXIFG` be evaluated as a Boolean operation? Would IFG2 be evaluated by its LSB?

The LSB is another interrupt flag `UCA0RXIFG`. If the above is true, why wouldn't the programmer just write `UCA0RXIFG&UCA0TXIFG`?

Comment: I think you confuse the & and the && operators. The && operator compare bool values. The & compare bit values and return data. E.g. 1 & 1 == true so outputs 1 for the bit compared. If you have 8 true bits then 11111111 is the outputs. Then with the ! expression you want the opposite of the boolean value.

Comment: Any integral or pointer value can be used as a boolean. Zero and null pointer mean false and nonzero and non-null are true.

Comment: @AlexandreTryHardLeblanc `&&` doesn't "compare bool values". It operates on integers and pointers and yields an `int`. However, it performs a **logical** and operation (i. e. it yields 1 if both arguments evaluate to non-zero, 0 otherwise).

Comment: @OP: C didn't even have Booleans under C99. You need to read a beginner C book.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yea my bad, what I wanted to say was indeed a logical 'and' operation. I should fix that language of mine. Not sure it makes a big difference to op though

Answer (score 0):

> How would IFG2&UCA0TXIFG be evaluated as a Boolean operation.

It wouldn't.

It is evaluated normally. The result is an integer, which is then in a boolean context - a logical negation. Any non-zero integer is true in a boolean context.

> why wouldn't the programmer just write UCA0RXIFG&UCA0TXIFG?

If I understood it correctly, those are just two constants: bitmask used to get specific bits of the state. Since they are constants, they don't depend on the system state, and the result would be an infinite loop.

You should check the [Bitwise operators in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).